# Haskell - List comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, integer, list-comprehension

My exercise is to define a function that returns a list of the prime numbers with at least three digits in a given interval. It has to be with list comprehension.

for example, in this case, it has to return primeNumbers 100 200 = [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199].

This is my code

```
primesNumbers :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
primesNumbers a b = [n | n <- [a..b], n > 99, all (\x -> n `mod` x /= 0) [x | x <- [2.. max a b]]]
```

But is this case primeNumbers 100 200, it returns just [].

What's the problem?

Comment: Hint: is 13 divisible by 13?

Comment: `[2.. max a b]` in your test is `[2.. 200]`. Is there a divisor of 101 in that range? Of 103? Etc.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem**

First, let me remark the fact that `n > 99` is probably not needed. If `a` is greater than 100, `n` cannot be lesser than 99. Either you want all the prime numbers greater than 99 or you did some mistake.
So I will work without it.

If we decompose your code, it is possible to write

```
primesNumbers :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
primesNumbers a b = [n | n <- [a..b], f a b n]

f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
f a b n = all (\x -> n `mod` x /= 0) [x | x <- [2.. max a b]]
```

If we want to provide a better name for `f`, we can look at the code and see that it tries to test if all the number between 2 and `max a b` is a divisor of `n`. So let call `f` the function `can_be_divided_by_a_number_between_a_and_b`.

So your function now is

```
primesNumbers a b = [n | n <- [a..b], can_be_divided_by_a_number_between_a_and_b a b n]
```

When you call `primeNumbers 100 200`, you want to find all the number `n` between 100 and 200 that can't be divided by a number between 2 and 200. Now, is 101 a relevant choice ? No because obviously 101 can be divided by a number between 100 and 200... it can be divided by itself.

**The solution**

Now you can see that this is not what you want. Your upper bound is too high. You want to find a way to express that it can't be divided by a number strictly between 1 and itself, i.e *]1, n[* or `[2 .. n-1]` in Haskell.

Let find a way to write `cant_be_divided_by_a_number_stritly_between_2_and_itself`. I will call it  `is_prime` for the sake of conciseness and because this is its definition.

```
is_prime :: Int -> Bool
is_prime n = all (\x -> n `mod` x /= 0) [x | x <- [2 .. n-1]]
```

and now it is easy to write your function. Since you want all prime numbers between `a` and `b`, it is

```
primeNumbers a b = [n | n <- [a..b], is_prime n]
```

**The conclusion**

In my humble opinion, you should have start with the latter... Writing

```
primeNumbers a b = [n | n <- [a..b], is_prime n]
```

is a beginning of a top down approach that helps you to decompose your problem into smaller problem and providing the solution step by step.
Writing the next step `is_prime n` is considerably easier than trying to solve all the problem in one step.

You could see that it can be generalized easily to all possible predicate `p` with

```
verify_p_between_a_and_b p a b = = [n | n <- [a..b], p n]
```

So

```
primesNumbers = verify_p_between_a_and_b is_prime
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

You are checking with:

```
all (\x -> n `mod` x /= 0) [x | x <- [2.. max a b]]
```

This means that for `5` for example, which is prime, eventually it will produce `x = 5`, and a number is always dividable by itself.

Your prime checker simply checks if it is dividably by anything larger or equal to two, and each number larger then or equal to two has that property: it is dividable by itself.

You should make the checker more effective with:

```
primesNumbers :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
primesNumbers a b = [n | n <- [max 100 a .. b], all (\x -> n `mod` x /= 0) (2:[3, 5 .. n-1])]
```

But we can do this more efficiently. Indeed, we only need to check until *√n*, so we can stop searching a lot earlier. We also do not need to check any multiple of a previous prime *p*. Indeed, it is sufficient to check if a number *p* is prime if there is no smaller prime *q* for which *p=(n+q)×q* for any *n∈ℕ<sub>0</sub>*. I leave this as an exercise.